# Internal/external division of a line question with unknown coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I've been having trouble with this question:

"Given $K(3, - 1)$ and $L(-4, 2)$, find two positions of $A$ on $KL$ such that $KA = 2( KL)$."

Any help would be appreciated. The first thing I tried was to treat the ration as being $2:1$, and plugging it into the formula for the internal division of a line.

What do I do now,
Thanks.

Comment: What is the formula for the internal division of a line you are referring to?

Comment: mx_2+nx_1/m+n

my_2+ny_1/m+n

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with your formula, at least not in the form you have presented (which is very ambiguous, I might add, without any brackets).

However you can easily solve this problem using vectors. Let A be the point $(x_0,y_0)$. The vector $\vec{KL}=[-7,-3]^T$. The vector $\vec{KA}=[3-x_0,-1-y_0]^T$ and you want one of $$\vec{KA}=2\vec{KL}\\\vec{KA}=-2\vec{KL}$$ to be true.

Thus you have $$-7=6-2x_0\\-3=-2-2y_0$$
OR
$$-7=-6+2x_0\\-3=2+2y_0$$
which you can solve easily.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for internal division is

$$ x_{P}= \frac{k_2 x_{A} + k_1 x_{B} }{k_1 + k_2}  ,  y_{P}= \frac{k_2 y_{A} + k_1 y_{B} }{k_1 + k_2} $$

[image]

Just use $k_1=2$ and $k_2=1$, for internal division and $k_1=-2$ and $k_2=1$ for external division.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, setting the unkown point, A, to be (x, y) the length of segment KA is $\sqrt{(x- 3)^2+ (y+ 1)^2}$ and the length of segment AL is $\sqrt{(x+ 4)^2+ (y- 2)^2}$.  The requirement that "KA= 2(AL)" is that $\sqrt{(x- 3)^2+ (y+ 1)^2}= 2\sqrt{(x+ 4)^2+ (y- 2)^2}$.  Squaring both sides, $(x- 3)^2+ (y+ 1)^2= 4(x+ 4)^2+ 4(y- 2)^2$ which is the same as $x^2- 6x+ 9+ y^2+ 2y+ 1= 4x^2+ 32x+ 65+ 4y^2- 16y+ 32$.  That reduces to $3x^2+ 38x+ 56+ 3y^2+ 2y + 31= 3x^3+ 3y^2+ 38x+ 2y+ 87= 0$.  That is a quadratic equation in two unknowns.  We can get the second equation we need from the fact that A lies on the line from K to L.  The slope of the line from K to L is $\frac{-1- 2}{3-(-4)}= \frac{-3}{7}$.  The slope or the line from K to A is $\frac{x- 2}{y-(-4)}= \frac{x- 2}{y+ 4}$.  Since K, L, and A all lie on the same line, those are equal: $\frac{x- 2}{y+ 4}= \frac{-3}{7}$ so $7(x- 2)= -3(y+ 4)$ or $7x+ 3y= 2$.

To solve those we could, for example, let $y= \frac{2}{3}- \frac{7}{3}x$ to get a quadratic equation In x only.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

What is the vector that joins $K$ to $L$?

Can you "divide" this vector in a ratio of 2:1?

Now just add the above on to the position of K.

As for the other position, I wouldn't say this is on KL per se as this will be an "external" point. By drawing a diagram, can you see where such a point could be? Hence find the required ratios and proceed.

Comment: Im still not sure what to do. Can you just provide a step by step explanation?

Comment: are you familiar with vectors?

Comment: No, I am not...

Comment: Oh. Think about the vector from K to L as just how much you need to move in each direction to get from K to L i.e. (move in x-direction, move in y-direction). You need to include signs as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that **A** lies on extended **KL**.
 Now case 1-
 A lies to the right of **L** so that **KA=KL+AL**
So **AL=KL** i.e **L** is mid point of **KA**. So **A** is **(-11,5)**
Case 2:
**A** lies to the left of **K** So **K** divides **AL** in 2:1
So from the formula of internal division we get **A** is **(17,-7)**
Let me know if I did the calculation wrong